# jQuery - Correctly displaying checked count number

Tags: jquery, checkbox, jquery-ui-widget

I'm using Eric Hynds jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget and trying to only display the check boxes from the widget itself. The "normal" checkboxes should not affect the count. Currently, the normal check boxes add to the count if you check one, then check one from the widget...resulting in count=2.

Please see my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PdLBX/6/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".multiselect").each(function () {
          $(this).change(updateCount);
        });
        updateCount();
        function updateCount () {
          var count = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").size();
          $("#count").text(count);
        };

      });
```

I've tried something like this but no luck.

```
 function updateCount () {
          var count1 = $("[id^=ui-multiselect-dropdown1]:checked").size(),
              count2 = $("[id^=ui-multiselect-dropdown2]:checked").size(); 
          $("#count").text(count1+count2);
        };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.length`

```
function updateCount () {
  var count1 = $("[id^=ui-multiselect-dropdown1]:checked").length,
      count2 = $("[id^=ui-multiselect-dropdown2]:checked").length; 
  $("#count").text(count1+count2);
};
```

Documentation [Here](http://api.jquery.com/length/)

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Property 'length' of object [object Object] is not a function`

Comment: You are getting that error becuase you are using brackets after the .length property. The usage of the length item is `.length` and not `.length()`